# Hibernate: Call a SequenceGenerator manually?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have written my own IdGenerator:

```
public class AkteIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
   public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
         throws HibernateException {
      // if custom id is set -> use this id
      if (object instanceof SomeBean) {
         SomeBean someBean = (SomeBean) object;
         Long customId = someBean.getCustomId();
         if (customId != 0) {
            return customId;
         }
      }
      // otherwise --> call the SequenceGenerator manually
      SequenceStyleGenerator sequenceGenerator ...
   }
}
```

Does anyone know how I could call the sequenceGenerator from my generator class what I normally can define per annotations:

```
@GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "MY_SEQUENCE")
@SequenceGenerator(
        allocationSize = 1,
        name = "MY_SEQUENCE",
        sequenceName = "MY_SEQUENCE_NAME")
```

I would be very thankful for any solutions!!!!

Thanks a lot, Norbert

Answer (score 6):

You can eassly call the SequenceGenerator from your Generator class. By writing this code.
THe  Custom generator class should be

```
 public class StudentNoGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)throws HibernateException {

    SequenceGenerator generator=new SequenceGenerator();
    Properties properties=new Properties();
    properties.put("sequence","Stud_NoSequence");
    generator.configure(Hibernate.STRING, properties, session.getFactory().getDialect());
    return generator.generate(session, session);

}
```

}
In the above code Stud_NoSequence is the Sequence name, which shoulb be created. in Data base by wring `create sequence Stud_NoSequence;`
Hibernate.String is the type which will be return by the SequenceGenerator class.

and the domain class will be

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    @Entity
    @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(
    name = "Custom-generator",
    strategy = "com.ssis.id.StudentNoGenerator"
    )
    public class Student {
@Id @GeneratedValue(generator = "Custom-generator")
String rno;
@Column
String name;
public String getRno() {
    return rno;
}
public void setRno(String rno) {
    this.rno = rno;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps, but I kept coming across this post while searching for my answer, which I didn't find posted anywhere, but found a solution myself. So I thought this might be the best place to share.

If you are using hibernate as the JPA provider, you can manually call an ID generator assigned to a given entity class. First inject the JpaContext:

```java
@Autowired
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaContext jpaContext;
```

Then obtain the internal org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator with this:

```java
org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor session = jpaContext.getEntityManagerByManagedType(MyEntity.class).unwrap(org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor.class);
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator generator = session.getEntityPersister(null, new MyEntity()).getIdentifierGenerator();
```

Now you can obtain an ID from the generator programatically:

```java
Serializable id = generator.generate(session, new MyEntity());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  @Id
  @GenericGenerator(name = "seq_id", strategy = "de.generator.AkteIdGenerator")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_id")
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private Integer Id;
```

http://blog.anorakgirl.co.uk/2009/01/custom-hibernate-sequence-generator-for-id-field/

Answer (score 0):

Your post was helpful to update the name of the sequence.

Because I use a sequence per month, and the configuration does not update each identifier generation.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor sessionImplementator,
        Object object) throws HibernateException {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    // If month sequence is wrong, then reconfigure.
    if (now.get(Calendar.MONTH) != SEQUENCE_DATE.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
        super.configure(new LongType(), new Properties(),
                sessionImplementator.getFactory().getDialect());
    }
    Long id = (Long) super.generate(sessionImplementator, object);
    String sId = String.format("%1$ty%1$tm%2$06d", SEQUENCE_DATE, id);
    return Long.parseLong(sId);// 1301000001
}
```